# Javascript remove all ',' in a string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript, replace

i want remove all ',' from my string with regex in javascript.

this is an example from my string:

> 45,454,545

and i want my string convert to this:

> 45454545

Comment: `"45,454,545".split(",").join("")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comma isn't a special character in regex, so you can just use `/,/`.  Add the global flag and you're done.

```js
console.log('45,454,545'.replace(/,/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  var str = "45,454,545";
  var res = str.replace(/,/g, "");
  console.log(res);
```